# IFrame of local HTML file not displaying in Jupyter nbviewer

Tags: html, iframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to share a Jupyter Notebook containing some regresison results (in an IFrame) with my university lecturer because I need to ask him something. The regression results are in a HTML file, generated from the `stargazer` library in R. The notebook can be viewed here: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/dl.dropbox.com/s/vnt875efjwqbi2g/regressions.ipynb?flush_cache=True. Is there any way to render a local HTML file in the notebook without it breaking for other people? I have tried using nbconvert to convert my notebook to HTML, but though I can see the IFrame properly, others cannot.

The folder is synced to Dropbox, and currently what I see in the IFrame is just this error:
Error (403)
It seems you don't belong here! You should probably sign in. Check out our Help Center and forums for help, or head back to home.

Of course, I could link my lecturer to the HTML file that contains the results, but that is not optimal because he has to jump between the nbviewer page for the code and the results page for the results.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a workaround. Since the HTML results file is hosted on Dropbox, [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/764641/how-to-serve-html-off-my-dropbox/931469#931469) explains how to access the contents of the HTML file directly from a Dropbox shared link. I can then display the IFrame using the Dropbox link instead of my local file.